# unable to use movement keys after moving the camera close to object

Tags: camera

I was trying to get he camera close to a very small object. But immediately after it wouldn't allow me to use any buttons to zoom in or out.

I checked and it wasn't a hardware issue, as the on-screen button would zoom in/out either. I saved and closed my program, and signed out of my computer, and opened the page again, and the issue still persisted.

Is this a glitch or an accidental feature i didn't realize?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE, could you show a picture of your screen while the problem is in action?